# Does AndroidStudio 32bit that worked on win8 x86 working on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, android-studio, x86-64

it is so simple but i want to sure that AndroidStudio with 32bit version can working on win 10 x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works. But why not use the x64?

Comment: thanks for answering....i have no time to download x64 version of android studio for now because with my internet speed it seperate about 5 hours and its to late for me....thanks